# Expect script not sending password as planned

Tags: bash, arch-linux, expect, konsole

I've tried reading up on this, but I can't figure out why it's happening.

When Expect sends the password it appears as echoed cleartext in the terminal and afterwards "Sorry, try again." appears.

The script goes as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn bash
send -- "sudo (many tasks)\r"
expect -exact "\[sudo\] password for elade: "
send -- "password\r"
expect -exact "user@x.x.x.x's password: "
send -- "password\r"
expect "@"
send -- "echo Done; sleep 1; exit\r"
expect eof
```

The terminal output after sending first password is:

```
[sudo] password for elade:
password
Sorry, try again.
```

I'm using Arch linux and the terminal emulator Konsole.

Comment: try a small delay between the expect and sending the password.

Comment: 1 sec, still the same. Tnx anyway

Comment: Try replacing the sudo command with od -c. See exactly what is being sent by your script to sudo.

Comment: When generating using autoexpect, the script halts and does nothing after the first sudo command is run.

And if replaced sudo with od -c  the output says that the following command is No such file or directory.

Comment: Append: I looked at the auto-generated script and added \r where the script halted. After that, the same thing happens. Password showing in terminal output and that it is wrong.

Comment: an aside: why not just `spawn sudo (many tasks)` instead of running bash first?

Comment: You can get lots of debug trace output by replacing the `-f` by `-d` on the first line.

Comment: do not try to match exact... in the last expect match only for "assword:"; do the something similar for the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the input above. After trying all the suggestions, the original script suddenly just started working again. When prompted for password, and the password got sent by expect, it did not appear in the terminal as before and was rejected, it was passed invisibly to the terminal and accepted, as if I was typing myself.

So I ran the script a few times and 1/10 times the same problem still persisted. There are three different passwords that needs to be sent, and which one "passes" and which one gets "echoed" in the terminal and rejected seems random. I don't why this is happening, but I suspect it has little to do with Expect and the actual script.

Comment: I just came across a similar issue. I am trying to send a password to R script using expect, and the issue is occurring only randomly, approximately once in 10-14 runs.

Comment: I'm just throwing a hypothesis here: The command that present password prompt may be occasionally facing some delay between writing the "Enter password" message to stdout, and starting the wait to read password from stdin, but expect may be sending the password too soon immediately on seeing the expected prompt text, and therefore the input sent to stdin by expect is not recognized as the password input for the prompt. So it gets echoed as plain text. Then the prompt actually opens and waits for input but expect thinks it has already done its job. So the scripts ends up waiting indefinitely

Comment: So I have experimentally added a `sleep 1` just before the send command in my expect block.